# Uncontrolled Memory Allocation error in PERL

Tags: perl, checkmarx

Checkmarx, a static analyzer tool is throwing security issue with the below code, saying that $file_list is accessing Uncontrolled Memory Allocation.

```
open ( INFILE, "<", "$inputfile" ) || die( "Cannot read list file $inputfile" );

while ( <INFILE> )
{
    $file = $_;
    chomp ( $file );
    $file_list{$file} = "1";
}
```

I tried to restrict the size of the hash variable as mentioned below but the error is not resolved.

```
    if(length($file) <= (1 * 1024 * 1024))
    {
        $file_list{$file} = "1";
    }
```

Kindly help me to understand the reason and with possible solutions.

Comment: Tip: Stop using global variables for nothing. `open ( INFILE, ... )` should be `open ( my $INFILE, ... )`

Comment: Tip: `"$inputfile"` is a needlessly slow and complicated version of `$inputfile`.

Comment: Tip: Does it really make sense to silently ignore long lines?

Comment: Tip: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". It's not an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which the size of the hash is dependent on user data.

- The length of the lines.
- The number of unique lines.

Your check accounts for one, but not the other.

Mind you, `<INFILE>` alone "suffers" from "uncontrolled memory allocation". If you allow that, what's the point in limiting the size of the hash?